# Cual es la diferencia entre . y # en CSS

Tags: css

Cuál es la diferencia entre **`#`** y **`.`** al declarar un conjunto de estilos para un elemento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En CSS existe algo llamado selectores, entre ellos se puede seleccionar por ejemplo elementos directamente como p, a, img, etc.
O también se pueden usar selectores de clase o Id.
"." Se utiliza para seleccionar elementos por su clase y "#" se utiliza para seleccionar elementos por su Id.

Ejemplo:

```
 <div id="ejemploId" class="ejemploClase">
```

Para seleccionar el div por su id usarías en CSS "#ejemploId", en caso de desear seleccionar el div por su clase usarías ".ejemploClase".

Una diferencia para su aplicación podría ser si deseamos aplicar los estilos a un único elemento en cuyo caso se suele utilizar id o si se desea aplicar un grupo de reglas a varios elementos, en ese caso aplicamos la misma clase a todos los elementos que se desea afectar.

Comment: y cual seria la diferencia entre el `ejemplo[id="ejemploid"]` y el `#ejemploid` ?

Comment: En el caso de los [ ] también son parte de los selectores, se podría hacer algo específico como div[class*="ejemploClase"], me refiero a específico porque podrías aplicar la clase a diferentes elementos div, p, span, etc., pero este selector solo afectaría a los div que cumplan con el atributo y valor especificado adentro de los [ ].

Comment: Gracias Luis, ahora me queda mas claro

Comment: A las órdenes, en el caso de los id quizás esta última sintaxis no tiene mucho sentido porque #id es muy específico, pero en el caso de las clases por ejemplo puede ser útil especificar a que elementos con esa clase queremos afectar.